# Google Colab: Runtime disconnecting

Tags: google-colaboratory

In Colaboratory, my session is always disconnected a few minutes after connecting to the GPU runtime.
There is no error, and just show that the runtime has been disconnected.
The problem started suddenly a week ago. Before that it was working normally with the same program.

I'm doing very general machine learning tasks and never doing any mining or anything like that, but has my account been restricted in any way?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()

# add empty color dimension
x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, -1)
x_test = np.expand_dims(x_test, -1)

[def create_model():
  model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(input_shape=x_train.shape\[1:\]))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (5, 5), padding='same', activation='elu'))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2,2)))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25))

  model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(input_shape=x_train.shape\[1:\]))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (5, 5), padding='same', activation='elu'))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25))

  model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(input_shape=x_train.shape\[1:\]))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (5, 5), padding='same', activation='elu'))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2,2)))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25))

  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('elu'))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('softmax'))
  return model

model = create_model()
model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3, ),
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=\['sparse_categorical_accuracy'\])

model.fit(
    x_train.astype(np.float32), y_train.astype(np.float32),
    epochs=50,
    steps_per_epoch=60,
    validation_data=(x_test.astype(np.float32), y_test.astype(np.float32)),
    validation_freq=17
)]
```

[Notebook screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcFdq.png)

Comment: Please share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the problem you observe.

Comment: Bob,
Thank you for the reply. I added the code and screen shot of a notebook.

Comment: Please share a link to a notebook where you observed this problem rather than a screenshot or code snippet.

Comment: Bob, thanks. However, this problem does not happen if you run it on other accounts. Additionally, since sharing the drives in this account with others is not allowed by the administrator, the link cannot be made public.